# Generating a truly unique order id in PHP?

Tags: php, unique-key

I'm considering using this: http://phpgoogle.blogspot.com/2007/08/four-ways-to-generate-unique-id-by-php.html

My idea is to use a mixture between 2 and 3. But my question is that, although the chances are small, is there still a chance that two orders with the same order # can be generated if I substring the result to be only 5 characters long? What about 3? 2? 1? Surely if it's 1, there is a 1/(26 + 10) chance that the id will be the same?

Comment: the first code example at the posted link is already crap: he forgot the put quote around his string (i don’t think that’s a constant)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your users are authenticated and have a user id:

```
$unique_id = time() . mt_rand() . $userid;
```

If the same user requests this page a second time in the same second, there will still be a chance of 1 in `mt_getrandmax()`, which on my machine returns 2147483647. You can probably live with that?

If your users are not authenticated, you can use a hash of their IP address instead if you'd like.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need a unique ID ?

If you want to generate a unique ID in your DB, then leave it to your DB, using auto-increment.

Anyway, you could use a combination of microtime() and rand(). You be pretty unique.

**Edit, relative to OP's comment :**

You can't have a "always unique" if. Or if you find how, you'll win a turing award.

Even better mathematical approches leaves you with a taste of "yes but once in 15645736536475 times, I'll get screwed".

Only way is to have counter, that you increment everytime you need a new ID. That's how DBs do. Why do you need the Id before inserting ?

Comment: I want a unique id BEFORE I commit to the db. And I agree, it would be "pretty unique". How can I get one that is ALWAYS unique, without storing it in a DB.

Comment: How do you think this is possible? To generate an "always unique id", you would not only have to know all ids that have been generated before, but also any id that will be ever generated... Have fun figuring out how to do that...

Comment: @x3ro: that's a bit of an exaggeration...if you assume that the algorithm itself doesn't change, then you can guarantee a unique ID by knowing *either* all past IDs *or* all future IDs. And with our current technology, the former is easier to implement!

Answer (score 3):

If you're relying on a random string then yes, it is theoretically possible that two IDs will be the same. That's why a long random string is used, to make that possibility so unlikely as to be acceptable. The probabilities can be calculated: for example if an ID is composed of the current time (to the nearest second) and a random 5-character alphanumeric string, and supposing that 3 IDs are generated in the same second, then the odds of two (or more) being the same is:  1 - (38^5! / (38^5-3)! / 38^5^3) = 3.79e-8. Most people would agree that such odds are *not* low enough for practical applications, which is why the page you linked to suggests 10 characters instead.

If you have a session ID, username, etc. then you can use that in the order ID, to help matters.

Comment: I agree with the mathematical approach. IMO 1E-15 **begin** to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

taken from PHP’s [uniqid](http://php.net/uniqid)’s manpage:

```
$better_token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
```

though it might be better to leave the `md5`-part out (reduces the number of tokens to 2^128)

if your using a database, then yes, you should let your DBMS handle the generation of id’s

Answer (score 1):

**You can use microtime and sha256 hashing, or without hashing.**

```
 $generate_order_id  = hash('sha256', microtime() );
```

Answer (score 1):

if your using a database you should let your DBMS handle the generation of id’s.

If you want to do it by yourself there is way... not the best one but it gets the job done.

First get all the existed uids from db and then make a do while loop...

```
$uids_in_db = []; //<< get here the uids from id. Use array_flip so the uids to be the keys in the array ( because isset is faster than in_array )

do{

    $uid = generate_somehow_a_random_uid();

} while ( isset( $uids_in_db[$uid]) );
```

That way you want are not going to have duplicate uid and if so then the do while will create a new one.

> Note: by using this method you have to do extra query to db and use
>   function inside a loop so its not the fastest way...

Answer (score 1):

```
$order_id='T'.date('ymdhi').mt_rand(1000,9999);
```

I am generating unique order number using above even i get order more than 500 orders in minutes.

Comment: That's a terrible idea. Your solution still has a chance to have duplicated `$order_id`, as `date('ymdhm')` will produce the same value in the *same hour* (note the last `m` in the function means month instead of minute), while `mt_rand()` still has a chance to make a duplicated result within this 60 minutes. Read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#94959) more comprehensive solution.